# Difference between JAVA and PHP AES ciphering

Tags: java, php, encryption, aes

I need to exchange encrypted data between a JAVA application and a PHP website.
This is the code that's being used to encrypt data:

```
private static SecretKeySpec createKeyFromString(String plainKey) {

    MessageDigest sha = null;
    byte[] key;
    SecretKeySpec secretKey = null;

    try {

        key = plainKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
        sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        key = sha.digest(key);
        key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);

        secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");

    } catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return secretKey;

}

private static String AESCrypt(String password, SecretKeySpec secretKey) {
    try {

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(password.getBytes("UTF-8")));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
    return null;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(Pay.AESCrypt("password", Pay.createKeyFromString("key")));

}
```

The output for this program is:

```
aRtcSG0H5u9v7xVYClnYIw==
```

I'm trying to replicate this behaviour in PHP using the following code:

```
function createKeyFromString($key) {
    return substr(hash('sha1', $key), 0, 16);
}

echo openssl_encrypt("password", "AES-128-ECB", createKeyFromString("key"));
```

But I'm getting this output:

```
pE3cPGDFjM9vwWZ3EO8xDg==
```

I'm a bit lost as to why I'm getting a different ciphered string. I tried padding the data to encrypt in PHP using this function:

```
function pkcs5_pad($text) {
    $size = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $pad = $size - (strlen($text) % $size);
    return $text . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
}

echo openssl_encrypt(pkcs5_pad("password"), "AES-128-ECB", createKeyFromString("key"));
```

But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Check that you're getting the same keys from SHA1. In particular, `hash('sha1', $key)` return hex characters unless you pass `true` to the third argument. (Also, I really hope you're not going to use ECB mode in your final product.)

Comment: Thanks, that was it, I needed the third argument when generating the hash. Regarding ECB, the JAVA application using ECB that I have to exchange data with is not mine, so I have no choice.

Comment: If you ever get a chance to improve it, just switch to libsodium. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the third argument in PHP's hash function to get the raw output instead of the HEX version.